# Django and virtualenv folders

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I'm just beginning to develop on Django and I have a question on how to manage my project folder.

Should I put my website folder into my virtual env folder, or at the same level ?

Comment: Your virtual environment diectories don't have to be anywhere near your project files (I keep mine in `~/.virtualenvs`). You certainly shouldn't put the project files *in* them.

Comment: You should not add it into the virtual env folder. venv can locate in anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Not inside, but i suggest you to create a folder called 'envs' ( for all your virtual envs) and another called 'reps' or 'projects' at the same level (where you can put your projects) in order to have a good directory schema. Just a suggestion of course.